# Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' in python

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, odbc, pyodbc

I'm using a python script to connect to a remote MSSql server. I installed the required libraries in my OSX m/c and tried connecting using python shell but the operation fails. MSSql is not installed locally in my dev machine.

```
Python shell:
>>> cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
>>>
```

Content of odbcinst.ini

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
```

File reference of driver, it's present.

```
lrwxr-xr-x    1 biju  admin      56 Mar 23 07:57 libmsodbcsql.17.dylib -> ../Cellar/msodbcsql17/17.5.2.1/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
```

Using the file path directly in driver, the code works.

Found one more odbcinst file at /etc/odbcinst.ini

```
[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.13.dylib
UsageCount=1
```

No file present in the path mentioned above /usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.13.dylib. I'm not sure if these two versions of library are installed properly or has to be removed.

Comment: You could try `brew reinstall msodbcsql17` if you think your msodbcsql17 installation is broken. Also, when you installed msodbcsql13, did you notice the info notice that said you needed to run `odbcinst -u -d -n "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server"` before uninstalling it?

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue and I fixed it by setting the `ODBCSYSINI` environment variable to point to the directory containing `odbcinst.ini` - which in my case was `/opt/odbc`.

```bash
export ODBCSYSINI=/opt/odbc
```

Note that the environment variable must point to the **directory** containing `odbcinst.ini` and **not the file itself**.

Ensure that the environment variable is set in the script or shell that calls your Python code.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  Anyhow i have moved from here.

Comment: Thanks Will, this is the correct answer and should be marked as such.